# Question about 金欠で久しく in the sentence 金欠で久しくスタバに行けてないけど・・・

Tags: grammar

May I ask about the construction of this sentence?

> **金欠で久しく**スタバに行けてないけど・・・

I know the meaning is along the lines of ...but I don't have any money and can't go to Starbucks."

I understand `スタバにいけてないけど`.

What I'm not sure I understand is the construction of `久しくスタバ`. Is the adverbial form of `久しい` used in the same way as the て form when multiple verbs are listed? In other words, is `久しく` essentially "for a long time, and..."?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

久しく adverbally modifies 行けていない. I scrambled it back into a more common position here:

> 金欠で　　　　　　スタバに　　　久しく　行けていない　　　　　　　　けど
>   out-of-money-SO　starbucks-TO　a-while　go-POTENTIAL-TEIRU-NOT　but

"Uh, I've been out of money, so I haven't been able to go to starbucks for a while."

Comment: Me too! スタバよりコスタの方が安い^^