# What conjugation of 送る is used in 返事をしたつもりだったが、送れていなかった

Tags: translation, conjugations, て-form

What is the list of conjugation forms that occurred to 送る in the sentence

> 返事をしたつもりだったが、送れていなかった。

Answer (score 3):

It's the past-negative-potential-teiru form of 送る. This (て)いる refers to the continuation of state.

- **送る**: to send
- **送れる**: (potential) to be able to send
- **送れている**: (potential-teiru) have been able to send
- **送れていない**: (negative-potential-teiru) have not been able to send
- **送れていなかった**: (past-negative-potential-teiru) had not been able to send

The sentence means "I thought I replied, but [I noticed] I hadn't sent [the mail] (successfully)".

Related:

- [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)
- [Question about 金欠で久しく in the sentence 金欠で久しくスタバに行けてないけど・・・](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12267/5010)
- [ている vs ていた](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57195/5010)

Answer (score 3):

This 送れて is the *te*-form of the "potential form" 送れる of 送る.

The potential form is sometimes used to mean that something was done successfully

> メールを送れた
> I (successfully) sent the email (*lit.* I was able to send the email)

In the sentence

> 返事をしたつもりだったが、**送れて**いなかった

the *te*-form (which together with いる may be used to express a state) is used to express a state of "not having been sent (successfully)", so

> I was under the impression that I replied [to the email], but it hadn't been successfully sent